# TyPe LiKe ThIs AnD iRrItAtE yOuR fRiEnDs

Tags: code-golf

Your goal is to alternate uppercase and lowercase letters, while ignoring non-alphaneumeric characters.

```
Input => Output
abc => aBc OR AbC
a c => A c OR a C
abc123abc => AbC123aBc OR aBc123AbC
```

Shortest answer wins.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 116

```
s=>{x=!0;return s.split("").map(e=>{if(e.match(/[a-zA-Z]/))x=!x;return x?e.toUpperCase():e.toLowerCase()}).join("")}
```

Saved two bytes thanks to NTCG

Comment: x=!0 can return true save 2 bytes and if you use join("") => join`` save 2 bytes

Comment: You can save some bytes with template tags like `.join\`\`` instead of `.join()` and also you can use the spread operator to spread a string into an array instead of `s.split\`\``. `[...s]`. Not nearly as good as the answer on the other question but `l=(s,x)=>[...s].map(e=>e.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)?e[\`to${(x=!x)?"Upp":"Low"}erCase\`]():e).join\`\``